# How to import constraints in xna with fbx file created by maya

Tags: xna, maya, fbx

I have this problem: in Autodesk Maya I set "aim constraint" between two objects. I'm able to export this constraints in fbx file (if I import this Fbx in Maya again I see the constraints) but when I import this fbx in Xna, the constraints are not imported.
There is a method to handle the constraints in Xna?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have not come across any code or samples for this problem, so I think you may have to write the code yourself. If you modify the skinned model sample content processor, you could create a class that contained both a `SkinningData` and, say, `ConstraintData` objects, which you would have to write and put it in the `Tag` property of the `Model`. You could then modify the `AnimationPlayer` class to accept `ConstraintData` and use it.

Edit: here is a link to the autodesk site where they have an sdk for writing fbx files:

http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?siteID=123112&id=7478532